# How does usatoday change URL without reloading a page?

Tags: browser-history, history.js

Go to any [usatoday][1] page and click on any of the main menu, the URL changes but only part of the page is updated. There's no whole page reloading.

How do I do something similar using jQuery or any libraries?
i know there are library like history API and so,but this only works on HTML5 browsers but HTML4 like IE9 and lower uses hash change
**BUT** USA today works on IE and HTML browsers with no hash?
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

jQuery plugin [Ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/) can do this with history.js

And for more information about History API http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html